# Different default views for different groups

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am making a LOP list in our SharePoint site. With there being an column for each of the different buildings. I have created groups for each building and have put all relevant people for the LOP list into their corresponding building.

I have also created separate views for each of the buildings so that for each view you only see the LOP's for your relevant building. I do not want people from a certain building to be able to look at another buildings LOP, so is there a way to have a group only see the building view that is relevant to them?

Comment: One way is you can use Target audience as you have already created multiple views. But if use have Edit/Contribute/Full Control access on list then they can create another view with no filters which will show all items from list.

Answer (score 1):

Views are not permissions. If you really need to block users from accessing other items in the list, then you need to configure list item permissions, not views.

A simple way for users to see the view that applies to them is to create a different page for each building, and add the list web part to the page, specifying the appropriate view. Any user who views that building's page will see only items from the given view.

Answer (score 0):

Since we cannot set permissions for list views, you can display each list view with a list web part on a wiki page and then set target audience for list web part via Edit Web Part > Advanced > target audience.

Each group will be able to see only the list web part targeted to it.

This feature is not supported on modern pages.

Reference:

[Target files, news and pages to specific audiences.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-files-news-and-pages-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)